# Is there a reason not to wirk with AMP (automatic mixed precision)?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nvidia

According to: [Introducing native PyTorch automatic mixed precision for faster training on NVIDIA GPUs](https://pytorch.org/blog/accelerating-training-on-nvidia-gpus-with-pytorch-automatic-mixed-precision/)

It's better to use AMP (with 16 Floating Point) due to:

1. Shorter training time.
2. Lower memory requirements, enabling larger batch sizes, larger models, or larger inputs.

- So is there a reason not to work with `FP16` ?
- Which models / datasets / solutions we will need to use `FP32` and not `FP16` ?
- Can I find an example in `kaggle` which we must use `FP32` and not `FP16` ?